# Google Chrome Extension - reload CSS from Server

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a site that uses Google Chrome as its browser.
(Yes - I do not need to be compatible with any other browser - I guess I'm lucky as this is a feature requested by the user of the system ;-)

I am working on the layout of the screen in VS2008 and am changing the CSS files all the time.
I do not want to change my browsers settings and do not want to clear the cache.

All I need is a browser extension (icon) that when it is clicked re applies the CSS to the page after fetching the CSS from the server.

This functionality exists in the Web Developer extension but it adds some extra clicks I am trying to avoid.

Any ideas will be much appreciated as I am getting tired of all the extra clicks.

Thanks and enjoy life, Julian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS Reloader extension: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dnfpcpfijpdhabaoieccoclghgplmpbd, just press f9 to reload (obviously after installing it :P).

Answer (score 7):

I've been looking around for a Chrome extension that reloads CSS from the server without making the page "flickering".

Here's what I found:

**[J CSS Reload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/j-css-reload/nnmebjmgdonemncjdliomljdfhpnlekk/related)** actually does the best job in my opinion, although it flickers sometimes. You can even set a keyboard shortcut at the bottom of chrome://extensions/ by clicking on "Keyboard shortcuts" (although this seems to cause flickering constantly).

**[CSS Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-refresh/ojcnooebgeenefpfngjfifjcnhlkbbdd)** refreshes CSS, but causes flickering (when hitting CSS reload, then all CSS is gone until the CSS is refreshed which makes it hard to spot the differences between before and after CSS reload).

**[CSS Reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-reloader/dnfpcpfijpdhabaoieccoclghgplmpbd)** doesn't work for me.

Another option to consider is **[LiveReload.js](http://livereload.com/)** which auto-reloads your web-app while developing (not only CSS but also HTML, etc.). There's a free [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) and for Rack applications (like Ruby On Rails) there's the great [Rack LiveReload](https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload) gem.

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout Web Developer extention

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm

It has alot of great feature. One of them being able to reload the linked style sheets.